# UE5 - Add texture to landscape

Tags: unreal-5

I created a terrain in gaea and exported it to UE5.

Then I created a new material with this texture which is for my whole landscape:

[image]

Material settings:

[image]
The preview above is already looking good.

But this is the result:

[image]
[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by replacing the **LandscapeCord** (Landscape Layer Coords) Node with a Texture Coordinate node.

[image]

I had to experiment with the value UTiling and VTiling until the texture was matching with my terrain. In my case I had to use very low values, because my terrain was scaled to X 700 Y 700 Z 700.

Result:

[image]